# Как быстрее всего отсортировать 4 float-a

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка

Какой алгоритм будет самым оптимальным ? На вход массив из 4 `float` , а на выходе отсортированный.

Дополнение:

Есть прямоугольник, который можно вращать и прямая, выходящая из его центра. Определить какую сторону пересекает. Есть 4 критических угла( так как период два пи, а я использую единичную окружность, то максимальный угол прямой к оси X может быть 5.9999999.. пи, а вот один из критических углов больше двух пи (например третий угол, там примерно 1.2 пи, и я поверну прямоугольник на 1.5 пи, то придется отнять от критического угла 2 пи, чтобы сравнивать с прямой) Проверку хочу сделать такой

```css
if (lineAngle > angles[3])
            std::cout << "RIGHT";
        else if (lineAngle > angles[2])
            std::cout << "TOP";
        else if (lineAngle > angles[1])
            std::cout << "LEFT";
        else if (lineAngle > angles[0])
            std::cout << "DOWN";
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Слияние - 4 или 5 сравнений.

Comment: При таком количестве, по-моему, вообще не имеет смысла беспокоиться об эффективности :)

Comment: Понимаю, просто сортировка будет повторяться в секунду раз 20. Так что подумал, может и стоить немного задуматься

Comment: 20 раз в секунду - это, по большому счету, ничто...

Comment: Также понимаю, просто у меня не только сортировка ( И все таки какой то перфекционист-чайник сидит во мне).

Comment: Вы работаете с Qt?

Comment: Какова реальная задача? Вдруг сортировка и вовсе не понадобится (В данном случае требуется 5 сравнений)

Comment: Написал задачу.

Comment: Ну и не нужно здесь никакой сортировки.

Comment: А как тогда можно?

Comment: Нужно задачу поставить с чётким описание входных данных. В другом вопросе, на конкретику этого Вы уже ответ получили.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void sort_swap(float&a, float& b)
{
    if (b < a) ::swap(a,b);
}

sort_swap(a[0],a[1]);
sort_swap(a[2],a[3]);
sort_swap(a[0],a[2]);
sort_swap(a[1],a[3]);
sort_swap(a[1],a[2]);
```

Вот такой набросок на коленке. Не компилировал. Идея понятна, но для пущей эффектности можно расписать без вызовов функций, хотя, думаю, оптимизирующий компилятор и сам все сделает...

Исходя из того, что log<sub>2</sub>(4!) ~ 4.58, меньше 5 сравнений в общем случае не получится.